# Sort images quickly / image tagging

Tags: images, file-management, photography

I need to sort thousands of images quickly into two categories (good and bad). I know that in Picasa one can speed through images fastly and hit "space" to tag an image as "favourite".

Are there other softwares that can do this? Peferably:

- Running on other operating systems besides Windows (Linux / MAC).
- More lightweight than picasa.
- Being able to sort into more then two categories (eg "good", "medium", "bad").
- An open-source server solution would be nice as well, since then I could ask different people around the globe to do the sorting for me.